# MySQL Share table between two databases

Tags: mysql, database, share

I want to know whether my approach is incorrect here

I have a simple website which you can register for. It has a main database called `USERS` which has a table with a list of all the users, and then for every new user a new database is generated called `DB1,DB2,...,DBn`. The reason I did this is because there is a lot of information being stored per user and I thought this would be a better approach. However, now I am running into the problem that the user databases need access to the table in the `USERS` database (for a foreign key) and I can't figure out how to do that.

I admit that I don't have much experience with MySQL, so it might be a very bad decision making a new database for every user. Is this the case? How efficient is MySQL? Can I, for example, create a list for (hypothetically) 100,000 users where each user has a further 100 entries for, lets say pictures, they have uploaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely bad design decision.  What you want to do is create a single database for all of your tables in this application.  In your example, you would have one database (call it `MyProject`).  You would have a users table, call it `User`, that has all of your User entries in it--100,000 entries is a *small* database for modern hardware, so don't worry about it.  Then you'll have a table called `UserPhoto` which contains a reference to the primary key in `User` as well as whatever other data you need.

Comment: that won't be too difficult to convert. Just out of curiosity, does table size have any impact on search speed? For example if I have a table for photo comments, then assuming 100,000 users, 1000 photos per user, 100 comments per photo, that comes out to 100,000*1000*100 entries to search through when looking for the specific subset. Cheers

Comment: Table size impacts search speed, yes.  But what indexes do is make it so that every query isn't going to scan all 100,000*1000*100 rows.  It uses some method (depends on implementation) to perform a lookup on the data at a significantly lower cost.  Again, that 100,000/1000/100 structure is relatively small for modern databases.  With properly placed indexes you will be fine.

Answer (score 7):

I'm also looking into the same issue. And the solution I found: http://drupal.org/node/37075

You can create VIEW representing your common USERS table in each database.

```
mysql> use DB1;
mysql> CREATE VIEW users AS
mysql> SELECT *
mysql> FROM USERS.users
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make queries between databases using syntax

```
db_name.table_name.table_field
```